# How to write nested generic function

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a generic Heap Sort algorithm. I get the following error. What could be the reason?

> The type `T` cannot be used as type parameter `T` in the generic type
>   or method `Heap.MainClass.MaxHeapify<T>(T[], int, int)`. There is no
>   boxing or type parameter conversion from `T` to
>   `System.IComparable<T>` (CS0314) (HeapSort)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify the same generic constraint that T must implement `IComparable<T>` on the `HeapSort` function as well:

```
private static void HeapSort<T>(T[] items) where T : IComparable<T>
```

You specified this constraint on the `MaxHeapify` method and in order to call it, T must satisfy this condition.

Answer (score 1):

The `MaxHeapify<T>()` method has a generic constraint of `where T : IComparable` but your `HeapSort<T>()` method doesn't have it, and so the compiler is not able to resolve the call to MaxHeapify from HeapSort method. 
You should add a generic constraint of `where : IComparable` to your `HeapSort<T>()` method also.

```
private static void HeapSort<T>(T[] items) where T : IComparable<T>
```